# Visual Studio code after Update to 1.60.0 Integrated Terminal Issue (CWD)

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

After an update to version 1.60.0 the integrated terminal that I use by default (WSL Ubuntu 20) gives problems.
If I set WSL as the default Terminal, the right terminal (WSL Ubuntu) is started only if I click on "Open new Terminal".
If I close VSL and reopen it, a power shell is automatically launched.

If I use the function on an file: "open in integrated Terminal" a power shell is always launched, VSL seems to ignore the CWD parameter:

```
terminal.integrated.cwd ":" $ {fileDirname} for WSL-Ubuntu.
```

Comment: It's a bug, already tracked here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150. As far as I can tell the fix has already been released to insiders.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [regression](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150) introduced in 1.60.0 and fixed in 1.60.1, which has just been released (see the [updated release note](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60)).

So you just have to update VS Code to the latest version.